# How to circumvent F# file ordering and types dependency

Tags: .net, performance, f#

I have the following logical structure of my project in F# (in files order):

```
Collection Interfaces
Base Implementations
----> Methods that work on interfaces
        | -----> IMathProvider that works on Specialized Implementations is injected during runtime 
Specialized Implementations that inherit base implementations.
MathProvider that knows about specialized implementations and implements IMathProvider
```

Note that `MathProvider` depends on `Specialized Implementations` but is used above inside `Base Implementations`. F# file ordering doesn't allow me to use `MathProvider` directly inside `Base Implementations`, and I have to do a very dirty hack on [this line](https://github.com/Spreads/Spreads/blob/master/src/Spreads.Collections/Spreads.Series.fs#L66).
(inside the static constructor of a base implementation this calls a method defined at the very bottom that knows about all implementations and returns the interface).

However, since `MathProvider` is returned as an interface its methods are never candidates for JIT inlining, and recently I have learned that it is a very big deal in .NET for high-performance numeric code. Also, this reflection trick is so ugly that it makes me feel bad...

I need a sealed class implementation of MathProvider, which will be able to optimize for special cases. The major case is a data structure where keys and values are arrays (SortedMap<,>, similar to SCG.SortedList<,>). So I do not need to know about `SortedMap<,>`, but I need access to the two arrays and the size. I want to define an internal interface at the very top level:

```
internal interface IArrayBasedMap<TKey, TValue> {
    int length { get; }
    TKey[] Keys { get; }
    TValue[] Values { get; }
}
```

and make `SortedMap<,>` to implement it. Then I could check if a collection implements this interface and apply optimizations to that interface members. Optimizations are mostly P/Invoke calls to a native math library, so I believe type-checking and P/Invoke call overheads will be amortized vs applying a scalar function to each value sequentially.

Do you think this is a correct approach to overcome the F# file ordering and top-down type dependency in this case (vs ugly reflection on startup)?

In general, what are other ways to achieve the same result instead of marker interfaces? Maybe it is possible to change the whole project architecture to avoid such issues?

Comment: Why use F# if you find yourself fighting the language? I'm pretty sure an entire page of types defined with`type ... and ... and ... etc` is not idiomatic F# code.

Comment: F# has many other strengths. And usually file ordering is blessing.

Comment: Did you actually check that standard **I**nversion **o**f **C**ontrol is too slow? Also, I guess "[...] since MathProvider is an interface [...]" should be `IMathProvider`?

Comment: @CaringDev here performance is less important than inconvenience. But in general, yes, I have micro and macro benchmarks that show how slow interfaces are vs direct calls.

Comment: could you update a link? It's already dead.

Answer (score 0):

What are the entry points to your library?

If there is a limited number of them, you can hide them beneath a facade that will ensure your initialization logic gets called. Let's assume the user needs to construct a SortedMap as in your github doc example. Instead of having the user call the constructor, make the constructor internal, and instead have something like this:

```
type Spreads private () =
    static do Spreads.Initializer.init()

    static member SortedMap() = SortedMap()
```

At a later point you can change it to more proper factory that would inject the correct MathProvider through the constructor instead of doing the static init call.

So in short my advice would be to put another layer of abstraction on top of your existing API that will a) limit the number of ways users interact with internals of your library, b) ensure the dependencies have been wired up correctly - either by properly injecting them, or calling the static initializers at appropriate times.